# Cell In[49], line 9 consumer_secret = 'RI9RAV5RC6cXzZHAiuDN1vTTGXaFGLNYplpffntpLlVkTN3PWw' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, tweepy

```
import logging

import tweepy

logger = logging.getLogger("twitter")

twitter_client = tweepy.Client(

consumer_key = 'MY_CONSUMER_KEY'

consumer_secret = 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET'

access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'

access_token_secret = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'

Bearer_token = 'MY_BEARER_TOKEN'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

)
```

Error code

```
Cell In[49], line 9
    consumer_secret = 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET'
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of every line after `twitter_client = tweepy.Client(`, you need a comma to separate the arguments, i.e.:

```py
twitter_client = tweepy.Client(
consumer_key = 'MY_CONSUMER_KEY',
consumer_secret = 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET',
access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
access_token_secret = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET',
Bearer_token = 'MY_BEARER_TOKEN',
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret),
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret),
api = tweepy.API(auth)
)
```

Comment: Functions take the form `function(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, i.e. arguments are separated by commas. You have omitted the commas. The syntax error is because it is expecting a comma to end the first argument, but it has instead found a new variable declaration. I'll edit my answer for clarity.